# How to deal with datatype TIME in Illuminate/Carbon

Tags: datetime, time, eloquent

I am working with a database that has the following columns (MariaDB):

- EventDate  (Datatype DATE)
- EventStart (Datatype TIME)
- EventEnd   (Datatype TIME)

In the model I assign the first field (EventDate) with:

```
...
protected $dates = ['EventDate'];
...
```

which is then be formated later with:

```
$event->EventDate->formatLocalized('%a. %d.%m.%y')
```

Now, I want to set the format of the times with a simliar approach, but if I add the next field into the array:

```
...
protected $dates = ['EventDate', 'EventStart'];
...
```

And I receive the following Error Message:

```
Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unexpected data found.
```

Has anybody an idea how to solve that issue?
Thanks to you!

Comment: Those aren't dates so you probably can't add them to that array.  I have avoided using time columns for this exact reason when I know I'm going to need it to be formatted.

Comment: yes, i finally figured out that TIME comes as a String-Type in PHP and needs to be casted to DATETIME. I found a solution with an Accessor (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a column with the datatype TIME comes in PHP as a String-Type, I achieved my problem with an Accessor:

```
public function getEventEndAttribute($value) {
    return $this->attributes['EventEnd'] = (Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value));
}
```

and then I was able to give my own format in the outputting script:

```
$event->EventEnd->format('H:i');
```